# Основы программирования

Tags: java

Предоставлен код:

```
 public class Laba1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a = 3, b = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        { 
            for (int j = 1; j <= (a + i -1); j++ )
            { if (j <= (a - i))
            {
                System.out.print(".");
                b++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            b = 0;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Как работает данная программа, что такое i++, for, if.

В каких случая необходимо ставить {} ?

Comment: Любой учебник поможет.

Comment: С тем же успехом вы можете поискать в гугле основы программирования на Java . Вы получите те же объяснения которые вам дадут здесь и при том быстрее

Answer (score -2, accepted):

for - цикл, который выполняется, пока верно условие (i <= a);

i -  адресуемая иным способом область памяти, адрес которой можно использовать для осуществления доступа к данным и изменять значение в ходе выполнения программы

++ - инкремент увеличивает значение в переменной;

if (если) - оператор условия, который выполняется при верном выражении в скобках (j <= (a - i)). Если это выражение не верно, выполняется оператор else (иначе)

{} - их нужно ставить в тех случаях, когда используется неразрывная конструкция кода. Сложно объяснить это простым языком, но если проводить аналогии с русским языком, то основная программа - это текст, а конструкции, использующие '{}' - отдельные его предложения